# JPA annotation with association table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations, many-to-many, associations

I'm using JPA annotation with Hibernate and I don't really know how to manage an *association table*.

### The entity relationship

Here is my database schema as entity-relationship (ER) diagram:

```
  COUNTRY          COUNTRY_MOVIE        
|---------|*    *|---------------|      | MOVIE   |
| COU_ID  |<---->| COUNTRY_ID    |*    *|---------|
| LABEL   |      | MOVIE_ID      |<---->| MO_ID   |
|---------|      |---------------|      | LABEL   |
                                        |---------|
```

The table `COUNTRY_MOVIE` is an *association table* between `COUNTRY` and `MOVIE` with many-to-many associations (symbolized by the arrow-lines above where many-to-many expressed by `*  *`) .

### The entities modeled in code with JPA

In my JPA object I didn't create a `CountryMovie.java` class.

#### Country

But I use `@JoinTable` in `Country.java` as in the following code:

```
//Package, Import...

@Entity
@Table(name="COUNTRY")
public class Country implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="COU_ID")
    private Integer couID;

    @Column(name="LABEL")
    private String label;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to TFilmFil
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="COUNTRY_MOVIE"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="COU_ID")
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="MO_ID")
            }
        )
    private List<Movie> movies;

    public Country() {
        super();
    }
    
    // Other constructor, Getter & Setter, and "toString" method...
}
```

#### Movie

And in `Movie.java` I use only a `@ManyToMany` annotation :

```
//Package, Import...

@Entity
@Table(name="MOVIE")
public class Movie implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="MO_ID")
    private Integer moId;

    @Column(name="LABEL")
    private String label;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to TrPaysPay
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="movies")
    private List<Country> countries;

    public Film() {
        super();
    }

    // Other constructor, Getter & Setter, and "toString" method...
}
```

---

#### Issue 1: `LazyInitializationException`

I don't know if it's the best way to manage this kind of *association table* even if it looks OK.

But when I try to get all the countries of a movie I obtain a `LazyInitializationException` from Hibernate.

#### Issue 2: After I tried `FetchType.EAGER`

So I tried to add a fetch EAGER to each many-to-many annotation:

In `Country`:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
```

In `Movie`:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="movies",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
```

Then I obtain this :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons

### Questions

1. Do I have to create another java class to map `COUNTRY_MOVIE`?
2. Or is there a way to fix this problem by using the same java class as now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping is alright (you don't need a third class). You also don't need to make it eager fetch.  The problem is with the querying code.  You should make sure that the session is still open when you access the collection.

Update the question with your query code and I can tell you how to fix it.

Comment: It's ok i found the way to fix my problem by using a left join

Answer (score 1):

first in joinTable, teh join column must be the foreign key for country ans inversjoin foreign key for Movie :

```
 @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(
        name="COUNTRY_MOVIE"
        , joinColumns={
                @JoinColumn(name="COUNTRY_ID")
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="MOVIE_ID")
            }
        )

    private List<Movie> movies;
```

You can get all countrie for a Movie like that :

```
public List<Country> getAllCountriesOfMovie(Integer id){
        Query query=null;
        query = session.createQuery("from Country as c  left join"
                + "  fetch c.movies as movie where movie.moId=:movieId");
        query.setInteger("movieId", id);
      return query.list();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my query in `MyDao.java` to get all the countries and the movies associated.

```
@Transactional
public class myDao implements IMyDao, Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

    public List<Country> getAllCountries() {
        try {
            return em.createQuery("select cou from Country cou").getResultList();
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            // Throw Exception
        }
    }
}
```

I assume I need to explicitly retrieve the list of the movies by using a join.

Comment: If you write code in the getAllCountries to iterate over the Country collection and access the getMovies() collection it will work. If you try to do it from another method it will not work.  To fix the you need to move the @@Transactional annotation to the higher level (service or controller) or you need to use the OpenSessionInViewFilter if it is a web application.   The reason for that is the entityManager is opened before calling the method with @@Transactional and closed before returning from the method.